# ASM Segfault when accessing bss data with some registers (other than rbx)

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm

```
;Just a lab a lab to test some instructions.

            section .bss
arraySize   equ     50
array       resb    arraySize

            global  _start

            section .text
_start:     mov     rax, array
            mov     byte [rbx], 10

            mov     rax, 1
            mov     rdi, 1
            mov     rsi, array
            mov     rdx, arraySize
            syscall

            mov     rax, 60
            xor     rdi, rdi
            syscall
```

So  i write this code to test some weird segfault.
The issue remain in this instruction

```
_start:     mov     rax, array
```

When I try to access to the address of the bss data of "array" with a register other than bx it seems to segfault, i don't know why and i made my research.
If you have any clues i'll be happy to read them :)!

Comment: Well, on the very next line you do `mov     byte [rbx], 10`. That's probably where the segfault occurs in the case where you haven't put a valid address in `rbx`.

Comment: Oh god i'm so dumb... Thks for the answer